# Two Sonar reports generation for 2 branches under one project

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have a java-maven project named **clarity** which has one pom.xml file. we recently created a bitbucket account and created two branches one for development team and one for reporting team. It's like two teams make changes to their own branch. Now I need to configure jenkins for running separate sonar reports for this two branches with one project itself, how do i that. Should I change the pom.xml file or need to specify something in jenkins jobs. Please mention clearly as I am new to this jenkins config. 
Any help is appreciated, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You should differentiate the two copies using the `sonar.branch` analysis parameter, which you should be able to pass into the Maven analysis on the command line using, E.G. `-Dsonar.branch=reporting`

Comment: Can u please specify where should I mention this sonar.branch property and how do I do that

Comment: Clarified inline @Kreddy